# AngularJS: Tab panes vary in HTML markup, I want them to be created dynamically and filled with data provided by factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building a tabbed interface for displaying posts from various social networks (timelines) but not all tabs will have the same HTML markup. My factory service is returning JSON response so that part is fine.

Also, a sidebar contains tabs onto which I put ng-click for opening appropriate panes.

Now, I'm wondering if I should proceed with creating a custom directive to reside inside my tab-pane wrapper:

```
<div class="tab-pane">
    <div timeline=""></div>
    or
    <timeline></timeline>
</div>
```

If so, I'm unsure whether $compile is the right approach? I've read that it is rarely used but it seems to me that it would allow me to dynamically decide which custom directive template to use, based on the clicked tab.

If there is a better approach to the solution, let me know. I'm really new to AngularJS but I'm eager to learn it, and learn it properly, applying best practices whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way might be:

```
<div class="tab-pane" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-switch="tab.network">
    <div ng-switch-when="Network_A">
        /* Template for Network A here... */
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="Network_B">
        /* Template for Network B here... */
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="Network_C">
        /* Template for Network C here... */
    </div>
</div>
```

So, you will need to add a `network` attribute to the `tab` objects, which tells what is the type of the social network.

Using directives might be a more efficient solution, but also more complicated.